# How to pass request query parameters through a NodeJS application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm currently working on learning NodeJs and am running into a problem with passing query parameters.  The stack consists of express, request-promise, and mongodb.  The design of the application I'm shooting for is to have an `express.js` that is basically the UI app for users.  There is also a `server.js` that defines any REST api endpoints, and a `recipes.js` that handles running all the queries and any logic I would want.

Below is the `express.js` file that I mentioned before that would handle the UI:

```
// Node imports.
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const request = require('request');
const rp = require('request-promise');
const url = require('url');

const port = 3001;

// View configuration information.
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Routing.
app.get('/recipes', (req, res) => {
    console.log("TODO(map) In the express.js: " + req.query.count);

    var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: 'http://localhost:3000/recipes',
    json: true
    }

    // Run get and wait on promise before rendering.
    rp(options, (req, res) => {
    }).then((recipes_list) => {
    res.render('index-promise', { pageTitle: 'Recipes', recipes: recipes_list })
    });
})

// Server listening.
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on http://localhost:' + port);
});
```

You can see the app has a single URL route for now.  The `server.js` file below shows the API endpoints mentioned above:

```
// Node imports.
const url = require('url');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const port = 3000;

// API imports.
var recipeApi = require('./apis/recipes.js');

// Routing.
app.get('/recipes', (req, res) => {
    console.log("TODO(map) In the server.js: " + req.query.count);
    recipeApi.getRecipesByCount(req, res);
})

// Server listening.
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on http://localhost:' + port);
});
```

The final file, `recipes.js`, connect to the database and gets the data an kicks it back.

```
// Node imports.
const url = require('url');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Mongo imports.
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const Db = require('mongodb').Db
const Server = require('mongodb').Server

// Create a DB object so we can query the db anywhere.
const db = new Db('mydb', new Server('localhost',27017));

/**
 * Function for getting a certain number of recipes.
 * NOTE: The req object should include a "count" query parameter.
 * 
 * req: Request being passed in from the server.js
 * res: Response that will be sent back.
 *
 */
exports.getRecipesByCount = (req, res) =>
{
    console.log("TODO(map) In the recipes.js: " + req.query.count);

    if (!req.query.count)
    {
    req.query.count = 0
    }
    db.open((err, db) => {
    db.collection("recipes").find({}).limit(parseInt(req.query.count)).toArray((err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.send(result);
        db.close();
    });
    });

}
```

So at the end of all this, the issue that I'm running into is in the `console.log` calls both the `server.js` and the `recipes.js`.  The `req.query.count` value is undefined despite the fact that the URL I'm hitting is `http://localhost:3000/recipes?count=1`.  How am I supposed to pass the information the `req` object has to the other app (the REST API) so I can get that information to the end point and query the database correctly?

Comment: Either separate the API from the UI (preferred) or use one route handler... and check parameters in that.

Comment: The UI and the API are separate.  The UI is hosted on port 3001 and the API is on port 3000.  I run them in separate Node instance.  The `express.js` consumes the API at the port 3000.  Am I misunderstanding what these being separate means?

Comment: I missed that. What's going on here? `uri: 'http://localhost:3000/recipes'` - you aren't passing a query string.

Comment: Correct I'm not passing the query string in the URI being used to call to the API.  Do I have to grab the query string and rebuild the URI in the `express.js` file and send that in?  I thought that when I do the request-promise `get()` call I can pass in the `req` object and get the `count` value from that.  Is that not the case?

Comment: So once a GET request is made to `localhost:3001/recipes` a GET request to `localhost:3000/recipes` -- nowhere in there is `count` passed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're sending a request to the backend API on port `3000` with no query params. In your express.js file you have:

```
var options = {
method: 'GET',
uri: 'http://localhost:3000/recipes',
json: true
}
```

Which, as you can see, has NO query parameters. You need to add the params here. If you change this to the code below it should work:

```
var options = {
method: 'GET',
uri: 'http://localhost:3000/recipes?count=' + req.query.count,
json: true
}
```

Comment: So I do ultimately have to build up the URI with the query parameters again?  It just seems inefficient to have to grab the `req` object, loop over every entry in the `query` dictionary, and build up a URI again.  Is there not a better way of doing something like passing the `req` object in the `express.js` into the API call?

Comment: My question is: why are you passing through the request like this at all? Why not make a call to the backend API from the front end JS?

Comment: Is this not the standard way of consuming a web service using express?  I was lead to believe I was doing a pretty standard thing from the tutorials I've been reading.

Comment: Your Express server bit is a fine start, but if you're building a *front end* then you should be making an ajax call to the server from the JS code in the browser. Your front end server shouldn't be passing those requests through like this.

Comment: I can understand deciding to use an Ajax call on the front end but I'm using EJS and I believe the design behind it is to use the `render()` method with data stored up to pass it to a template page that can then take the data and populate the page where the place holders are.  I'm not sure how Ajax is able to help me there outside of I would return the data to the page directly and have to parse it and then insert to certain locations.

Comment: Eh... I could go either way. In any case, Express does not have a facility for passing through query strings like that. You could use [a library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) to do so, however.

Comment: Ok so there isn't anything really wrong with the design, just not a preference on design? (I'm not trying to be confrontational or anything I just want to ensure I'm not doing anything totally crazy here :-) ).

Comment: Can't answer the "totally crazy" idea, but from what I see it seems like just a lot of run around, not crazy. I'd probably just have the data access and front end rendering in the same Express server... But I know others would do it differently.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the info.  I appreciate the heads up about the Ajax call and I may change it in the future but either way it's good information.